# Can't get the value from JavaScript using Jsoup

Tags: java, android

I use Jsoup in Android and i want to parse the value which are movie name 、movie time and movie image from url.

I try some key values to get there which like

`Elements elements=document.select("ul");`

`Elements elements=document.select("div");`

`Elements elements=document.select("a");`

They are no working , i can't find the way to get there.

Why? Is my step wrong ? Or...is it  about JavaScript ?

If this is so , how do i solve my problem ?

here is my code include url , any help would be grateful , thanks.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String url = strings[0];

            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ambassador.com.tw/showtime_list.html#").get();
                Log.d("document", document.toString());

                Elements elements=document.select("div");
                Log.d("elements",elements.toString());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d("IOException", ex.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I update my question, i use `Elements elements=document.select("ul");`
it shows:
[image]

but i really want the "ul"is this:
[image]

How do i improve my step ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you trying to scrape but one thing you can do is to Change

> Log.d("document", document.**toString()**);

to

> Log.d("document", document.**text()**);

**toString()** will return you the full tags
but **text()** will return you the exact values.

Hope it helps !